# What do you call this black, rectangular clamp in English?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

I want to search for images of this clamp.  What do you call this in English?

[image: Clamp: The black, rectangular part grabs the paper, and there are two metal loops hanging off the top, which are squeezed to release the clip's grip]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74669/discussion-on-question-by-salman-what-do-you-call-this-clamp-in-english).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think the term is ***[bulldog clip](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/bulldog-clip)***:

> - a small metal object that shuts tightly to hold papers together.

*(source: Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English)*

[Bulldog clip](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bulldog_clip) (British)

> - A strong sprung metal device with two flat plates that close so as to hold papers together.

*(source: Oxford Dictionary) (British)*

[image: Black metal binding clip]

Comment: Please don't vandalise your answer. I understand that you no longer want to participate in the discussion surrounding it, however flagging your post would have been sufficient. I think if you highlight that your answer is specific to British English, then you should be fine. I'll back you up on that.

Comment: I generally think of bulldog clips as a similar but distinct design, as shown on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulldog_clip

Comment: @MattE.Эллен This answer isn't specific to British English: it's just wrong, and the poster is being prevented from deleting it because it's been accepted.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - well, the question isn’t specific to AmE either. The title and the body don’t mention AmE, just a tag. So both versions should be reasonably accepted. The problem is that the wider presence of AmE speakers want to focus on the term they know. As for the answer, it clearly states BRITISH.

Comment: @user5768790 No, the problem is that the question specifies American English but doesn't _clearly_ specify American English (it's hidden in a tag).

Comment: @DavidRicherby - I am not trying to support my answer, but the specific  request in AmE terms in unclear, to say the least.

Comment: The problem isn't about British/American English.  It's that the item is not a Bulldog Clip, it's a Foldback Clip.   Not a matter of brand name.  Quite different construction.  Some sources confuse the two.  Let's not perpetuate the confusion!

Comment: @DavidRicherby If you think the term applies to more than British English that' fine, but I'm 100% certain that the picture is of a bulldog clip. that's what I've called them ever since I encountered them and I didn't learn it in a vaccum.

Comment: Perhaps the clarification could be made that while in common speech - it is called a "bulldog clip", and calling it that will be understood (in UK). There is technically a difference between bulldog clips and foldback clips (still in the UK). It's definitely not incorrect to say "people call this a bulldog clip in the UK" - even if that's not technically the right term.

Comment: @DavidRicherby It's called a bulldog clip in the UK. If you ask the average administrator for a bulldog clip, this is what you'll be given. If you try to buy a bulldog clip, this is what comes up. That might not be its correct name, but that's what it's called.

Comment: I’m American and “bulldog clip” is the only name I’ve ever heard used for them (given of course that 90% of people have no idea what they’re named and just say “black clip thing” or similar).

Comment: According wikipedia, it's very explicitly **not** a bulldog clip. From the page on [binder clips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binder_clip): *The term "foldback clip" is used in the United Kingdom to describe this invention (not to be confused with a Bulldog clip, an older device with the same function, which is stronger and has rigid rather than folding handles)*

Comment: Whatever Bulldog may think of their patented name being applied to other types of clip, it's gone the way of Hoover and Sellotape.

Comment: I'm Australian and I have also only ever heard these called bulldog clips.

Comment: I’m Australian too, I’ve worked in office environments  for 40 years but I’ve never ever used the term “bulldog clip”. If someone asked for one by this name, I’d assume they meant the type shown in the image. I just call them “clips”. If I wanted to refer to the clip type properly known as a bulldog clip, I’d call it “one of those old-fashioned clips that do your fingers in”.

Answer (score 233):

***[Binder clip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binder_clip)***, also known as a *foldback* or *banker's* clip.

[image]

It is called a binder clip because the bent metal clips may be removed, creating a semi-permanent binding (see right).

Comment: Colloquially, I believe _binder clip_ is far more commonly used in the U.S. as compared to _bulldog clip_ (a name which I've never heard used before).

Comment: I am an AE-speaker with limited exposure to BE and had never encountered "bulldog clip" until just now. I find it curious that the asker tagged their question as pertaining to AE, but accepted an answer based on BE usage.

Comment: To be honest, before I looked it up, I just called it _one of those big black paperclip thingies_.

Comment: When I was in high school we called them "briefcase clips", for some unclear reason.

Comment: It looks like a briefcase with two handles, no?

Comment: @SeanPianka [**Bulldog clip**](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1309&bih=660&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=SSaPWtIYpZ3nApaYodAL&q=%22Bulldog+clip%22&oq=%22Bulldog+clip%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l7j0i67k1l2j0.1506.3839.0.4278.2.2.0.0.0.0.246.472.2-2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.471....0.y9UzBS65Pb0) is a British name, it's not wrong or inferior in any shape or form to *binder clip* a term I had never heard of, until today that is.

Comment: @Mari-LouA it isn't inferior, but it **is** wrong, considering the tag for American English. Without that tag, i would agree with you.

Comment: @AytAyt  Do you know how many times new users tag their questions with the first letter they happen to type? The editor added the SWR and Image-identification tags, so I wouldn't take that tag too seriously.... The truth is that SE is populated by mainly Americans, nothing wrong with that. I even adapted my spelling to fit in with all you guys :)

Comment: For what it's worth, I am an American who always thought those were called "bulldog clips" and had no idea that was considered to be a British term.

Comment: I've not heard of either _binder clip_  or _bulldog clip_, but the latter isn't nearly as obvious without context.

Comment: @Mari-LouA No, a bulldog clip is a completely different kind of clip, as your Google search shows. This isn't a difference between British and American usage: it's a simple case of different objects having different names.

Comment: @njuffa "Bulldog clip" isn't even the British name for those clips. A bulldog clip is a different kind of clip, which doesn't have the possibility of folding back the handles.

Comment: @DavidRicherby  A completely "different thing" it is not. A *bulldog* **clip** is still a strong clip which holds several paper sheets or attaches sheets of paper onto a cardboard, to make a **clipboard**. The fact that its handles cannot be folded back or detached (see image) is a specific feature of a *binder* **clip**, which also holds several pieces of paper or cardboard together.

Comment: @Mari-LouA They have the same purpose but they are very distinctively different designs that have different names. I really don't understand why you're disputing that they're different things.

Comment: @DavidRicherby there's a London shop that calls that article a [bulldog folding clip](https://www.lavenderhillcolours.com/shop/bulldog-folding-clip/) so, I am going to take a wild guess, that many British English speaking people would call it a bulldog clip, whereas Americans would call it a "binder clip". I believe that "binder clip" is an American and much older invention than its British near-equivalent.

Comment: Link to the 1910/1915 US patent labeling it as a "paper binding clip". https://patents.google.com/patent/US1139627

Comment: FWIW, "binder clip" is the generic term for these at both [Staples](https://www.staples.com/Clips-Fasteners/cat_CL10102?fids=&sr=true&sby=&min=&max=&myStoreId=) and [Office Depot/OfficeMax](https://www.officedepot.com/a/browse/paper-clips-binder-clips-and-fasteners/N=5+581682/), two major US office supply retailers. Staples, for example, has 36 items labelled "binder clip" (which look like the OP's picture), 4 labelled "bulldog clip" (which look like @Magoo's picture), and 2 labelled "butterfly clamp" (which look like a fancy, butterfly-shaped paperclip).

Comment: This answer is correct, while the (currently) chosen answer is incorrect. North America: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binder_clip - in England it's a Foldback, a Bulldog has solid (non-foldable) actuators.

Comment: -1 for using  an unreliable source as the only reference

Comment: @user1284969632635: I think wikipedia can be trusted when it comes to such simple matters as the proper designations for office supplies. You're of course welcome to refute it in a well-referenced answer of your own.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It depends on where you are. Calling this a *bulldog clip* in the US would, in fact, be wrong, because no one would know what you mean. That's a BrE-specific term. Remember that the primary purpose of language is to be understood.

Comment: In *Canada* and the *United States*, I have most frequently heard this referred to as a **bulldog clip**.

Answer (score 33):

This is a Bulldog Clip

[image: Bulldog clip]

so called because it is a brand name registered in 1944.

The type of clip in question is much later and inherited the name in some places and inherited the locally-applied name elsewhere. Sometimes it's called a "fold-back" clip.

I'd suggest the precise type has has a name that varies depending on the audience - and it's a little unclear whether OP is interested in the *precise type* pictured or the name(s) for *all* clips that would fulfill this function.

OTOH, it's *not* a paper-clip.

Comment: What about this:https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/bulldog-clip

Comment: @user5768790 : dictionary definitions are fine if you want to know what is meant by a word or phrase, but not when you need to find a word or phrase that means something. A bit like "help" functions nowadays - only useful once you happen on a keyword. "Bulldog" is a `proprietary eponym` - a proprietary word that has become synonymous with a function, like "Xerox=photocopy=photostat" or "Hoover=vacuum-cleaner". You might say you "vacuum" the floor or you "hoover" the floor and be just as well understood. You wouldn't say you "Dyson" the floor, though.

Comment: It would probably be called a "Bulldog Clip" as that is the name that has been used for decades for a device with a similar *function* that has largely been replaced by the clip that you originally posted. The usage would not be universally understood, but I doubt that any term would be in this instance. Were you to send ten people out in ten different locations on a mission to buy some "Bulldog Clips" or any other term that has been suggested, I would not be suprised at the variety of objects that would be returned.

Comment: +1 for the valuable and interesting history on "bulldog clip"!

Comment: I voted against the last sentence, which needs amendment. Yes, it is true that this is not the most common variety of paperclip, assumed by default, which is the metal wire paperclip, but I have heard them referred to them as paperclips before by a few people, and there [is no impropriety to categorically calling any device meant to clip paper together a paperclip](https://www.tfd.com/paperclip) (note that especially means *not exclusively*). You can even see in *[Rules, Britannia: …](https://tinyurl.com/y8fgok22)* by Summers Hargis that a bulldog clip is defined as "A larger black paperclip".

Comment: @Tonepoet If you wish to define all devices that may be used to keep papers together as "paperclips" then the plastic variety, staples, a paperweight of any variety (including a rock or can of beans) or even a folder or file may squeeze into your definition. Most people would immediately assume the metal type you mention. The march of time provides other products to fulfill the function, and they inherit the name. More than "a few people" refer to the case containing a computer's storage devices as a "hard drive" which it clearly isn't. Now we have SSDs, and they've started to inherit the name

Comment: @Tonepoet As for your other reference, since we're now quibbling about precision of definitions, I'd just point out that whereas the illustration is undoubtedly of a Bulldog clip as you can se by the brandname imprinted on it, it is  does not need to be large (I've seen them at ¼" long) nor does it have to be black.

Comment: @magoo Well that would be true if that was the point I was trying to make, but I am just suggesting that all of the items meant to clip paper with tension together count as paperclips: The folder acts as a container, the paperweight uses gravity, and the staple sticks them together for lack of a better word: None of those clip, so none of those count. If you hold a more restricted definition, we'll just have to agree to disagree. As for the reference, I only meant to show that the item in question is indeed sometimes considered a paperclip, not to imply that it should be called a bulldog clip

Comment: Yes, *that* is a Bulldog clip, but *that* is **not** what OP posted. The handles are different.

Comment: @Michael Yes, that's precisely the point. The clip I've pictured is a bulldog clip, OP's picture is not - it is sometimes called a "fold-back" clip, but it has also inherited the name "bulldog clip" by fulfilling the same function. It has different names in different places. There *is* an "official" definition of  bulldog clip by way of its being a proprietary item. There is no universally-accepted name for the object OP enquired about, but "bulldog clip" is one term that may be used in some places.

Comment: @Magoo then you should amend your answer to make that clearer. It reads like a headline stating that OP's clip is a bulldog clip.

Answer (score 12):

In Australia, I'm used to them being called *Butterfly Clips*. Since then, the same name has been attributed to a certain type of hair clips, however.

Comment: As an Australian, I've only ever heard these described as bulldog clips.

Comment: And I'm an American that has lived and worked in 20 US states, and butterfly clip is the only name I know for this thing. I have never heard of bulldog clips (although I still have several of those things identified as such). I have heard of binder clips maybe once or twice in my life. But I couldn't pin that term down to any particular item.

Answer (score -1):

I tried Amazon.com ...  I found both:
(1) Binder clip
[image: binder]

(2) Bulldog clip
[image: bulldog]
So, not the same.  (In the US)

(3) Butterfly clip  ... these seemed to be only hair clips.

(4) Foldback clip ... this search linked to "binder clips" (above); in one case called "foldback binder clips".

---

Trying amazon.co.uk ... "Bulldog clips" produced both kinds of clips.  With labels {Bulldog, Binder, Foldback, Letter} clips.